# How do I create a dependent list that shows on one sheet, references a second sheet, with the data from a separate workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm going to try to explain the problem sufficiently but I'm very new to this level of excel so I'm expecting the need to try and clarify for any questions. I also can't upload the original file so lets try imgs. Thanks for the patience.

I'm picking up the pieces for a work in progress after a coworker left the company. The excel program (wb1) is to create a shipping label (sheet 1) in a specific format [LABEL IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ImoL.png)

The blue area is all drop down lists from a data sheet (sheet 2). The location list needs to be a dependent list of the customer list that references a completely separate workbook with all customer info(wb2). When it works it will provide the shipping info for that location. We are at the manufacture level so a cust can have multiple locations.

The issue: only the first location and first customer work correctly [CORRECT IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3xLR.png). Any additional locations for cust 1 don't work, nor does any additional customers. [INCORRECT LABEL IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwNc3.png)

Here's the formulas as well as a pic w/ dependent traces :[FORUMLA AND TRACE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ivKV.png)

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,2,FALSE),"")=0,"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,2,FALSE),""))
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,6,FALSE),"")=0,"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,6,FALSE),""))
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,7,FALSE),"")=0,"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,7,FALSE),""))
```

Constraints: There is a possibility of VBA being used, but it is inaccessible as the person locked it and didn't give the password. I also can't just remake the entire sheet because I have no idea what other programs are referenced to this one. There's a considerable chance I would break something else. The last constraint is it has to work with wb2 being closed. The program will be housed in the cloud and used across all warehouses but ref a central file(wb2) also in the cloud.

I've tried:

1. Expanding the location list in sheet 2- this gave me the entire list of all cust locations for cust 1 but only the first time it was referenced. After that it went back to only the top cell.
2. Pointing the formula at a different cell in wb2- i expected this to produce that cells info. No change
3. Deleting and remaking the location table in sheet 2- no change

Answer (score 0):

You have too many issues presented in this message to find an easy solution. It's possible to crack a VBA password, but it will be not the end of your difficulties.
I have seen that your file use form, so behind this form you will find VBA code.

I have also remarked that the formula

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,6,FALSE),"")=0,"",
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($N$8&"|"&$AK$8,'Master Address List.xlsx'!$C$1:$I$20014,6,FALSE),""))
```

doesn't use the right rule for this function. Your ex-college, has put some trigger bombs on your road.

Sometime, it's easier to rewrite a new code and I can help you if you decide to rewrite this application.

Comment: You are 100% correct. Late Fri I was able to bypass the code. I still can't get it to accept a NEW password but at least I can work on it. I fixed some of the other issues and got a look at the code. I will edit this comment on Monday with the actual vba code that pertains to the issue.

Comment: Below is the VBA code that i think pertains to the location issue. The list will now give a dropdown just not a dependent dropdown. "J" is the parent cust list, "L" is the location list and "O" is the count of locations:

Comment: `Sub Location()
Dim ult As Long
Dim nr As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Data").Unprotect "***"

ult = Sheets("Data").Range("O1") + 1
If ult = 1 Then
ult = ult + 1
End If
nr = "$L$1:$L$" & ult
Range("Table6").Select
Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Table6").Resize Range(nr)
Sheets("Data").Protect "***"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`